# User can't install Android app on to supported device

Tags: android, google-play, android-market-filtering

A potential user of my Android app has contacted me to report that they are unable to install my app from the Android Market.

They receive the following error when attempting to install the application:

"Application requires features not available on your device."

My app declares the following requirements in its manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"
    android:required="true" />
```

The user's device is a Samsung Infuse 4G. I have been over the specs for Samsung Infuse and it is clear that has the necessary hardware to satisfy these requirements.

Moreover, the Samsung Infuse 4G is listed as a supported device for my app in the Android Market Developer Console "Device Availability" dialog.

Has anyone else seen this error? Can anyone suggest any possible causes for this error which could be addressed/worked around?

Many thanks.

Comment: The market should have filtered out any apps that don't have the required hardware. What version of Android are they running? Is it a stock or custom ROM?

Comment: As far as I know it's a stock ROM.

Comment: So what was the restriction? Can you answer your own question?

Comment: Unfortunately I never found an answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

When this happens on my app, I have a "debug" app that I temporarily publish in the market. I remove one restriction at a time until it installs properly for the customer.

Comment: Sounds like a useful approach.